# Can default values from SQLAlchemy models be read and used in your application?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a technical reason why an application can't or shouldn't read out the default values you establish for columns in your SQLAlchemy models, and use those defaults in other places in your application, such as when setting default values in the UI for those same columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLAlchemy's [column defaults](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/defaults.html) are much more complex than just simple values.  They can take:

- Simple values
- No-argument functions
- Functions with a context argument
- SQL expressions

SQLAlchemy only applies these defaults when inserting the instances, not when creating them, so the instance will not even have the defaults assigned until they are committed.

To handle the different types of default, SQLAlchemy does some magic to wrap the default, so it's hard/near-impossible/not worth it to get at the value that you pass in in the column constructor.

---

That's not to say you can't have some collection of default values somewhere else and assign those out in some way.  It's just not feasible to use the default values from columns.